# clear triplot from figure

Tags: python, canvas, matplotlib

I have a question about the function triplot from matplotlib.
I draw a mesh in a canvas with the function triplot, and I want to clear this mesh after an action. My canvas is embed into a area left in my glade window.
Here a piece of my code:

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtkagg import FigureCanvasGTKAgg as FigureCanvas
fig = Figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
place = builder.get_object("vbox_visu")
place.pack_start(canvas)
mesh = ax.triplot(x,y)
canvas.draw()
```

This work perfectly, but I don't now how to clear my mesh.
Specification: in background I use Basemap to draw continent (and BlueMarble)inter alia, and i don't want to clear the others figures.
I hope someone could help me.
Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your answer Joe Kington. It's work perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, matplotlib functions return the artists they add.

Unfortunately, `triplot` doesn't.  (This is arguably a bug.)  Notice that `mesh` is `None` in your example above.

However, `triplot` adds a `PathPatch` and a `Line2D`. These are appended to `ax.patches` and `ax.lines`, respectively.

Therefore, you can remove the mesh by doing:

```
ax.lines[-1].remove()
ax.patches[-1].remove()
canvas.draw()
```

This assumes that `triplot` was the last plotting function that was called.  (If not, just hang on to a reference of the patch and line by doing something like `line = ax.lines[-1]`, etc immediately after plotting with `triplot`.

Answer (score 0):

This should be solved in v1.4:

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2781